# Users can't upload files, even with permissions set to them using vsftpd

Tags: linux, vsftpd

I have a cloud hosting linux solution. I had vsftpd working on it, but after having issues and tinkering with a lot of settings, I now have an issue where users can login using FTP and connect to the correct home directory, navigate within it, download files but they cannot upload files to the server. They get a time out error, which appears to be a permissions error, but I can't narrow it down any more than that. /var/logs/syslog gives nothing away.

The folders belong to the users. The parent www folder is set to 555. Can anyone help with this issue at all?

Cheers,

T

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the permissions to `755`, `555` doesn't allow writing for anyone. Are your user and group different?

You also may need to enable logging for FTP server. The time out error may include some other errors, not only permission denied.

To have extended logging change the variables in your ftp config file:

```
dual_log_enable=YES
log_ftp_protocol=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
syslog_enable=NO
```

and check the log file name there.

Comment: I tried 755 and 777 (for the purpose of testing) to no avail. Any idea how I can turn on ftp logging? Total Linux noob.

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified, yes user and group are different. Group is www-data

Comment: I've found a link to logging. I'll turn this on now and give it a go. I'll report back with error log if I can't resolve.

Comment: I've added info about logging to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a mill Alec. Trying this now.

Answer (score 0):

you must create a folder into user folder (Example : /var/www/user1/upload).
and set permission 777 (Example : chmod 777 /var/www/user1/upload).
then upload file into this folder.