# vsftpd won't allow upload of files via ftps

Tags: ftps, vsftpd

I'm trying to set up an ftps server where I can upload files securely to a specific folder. I've set up the server and it will upload files just fine on regular, unsecure FTP. However, after I set up an SSL certificate and try to upload a file in FTP-SSL, it logs into the server just fine, but trying to upload a file causes my FTP client to hang without uploading any data until the connection times out. I've tried this on a couple of different systems both inside and outside my local network with the same result.

Comment: Visit this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465591/users-cant-upload-files-even-with-permissions-set-to-them-using-vsftpd][1]